# Using jti claim of JWT tokens as an opaque token

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, oauth, jwt

I have a use case where I need to get Both JWT and Opaque tokens from the server(for testing purposes). But either of only JWT or Opaque token can be configured to be retrieved in the Application.

Can I use the **jti** claim of JWT as an opaque token ?. According to the official docs, jti is a random unique ID per JWT token. So I don't need to write any logic to trigger another request with changes configurations to get an opaque token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official doc

> The "jti" (JWT ID) claim provides a unique identifier for the JWT. The
> identifier value MUST be assigned in a manner that ensures that there
> is a negligible probability that the same value will be accidentally
> assigned to a different data object; if the application uses multiple
> issuers, collisions MUST be prevented among values produced by
> different issuers as well. The "jti" claim can be used to prevent the
> JWT from being replayed. The "jti" value is a case-sensitive string.
> Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.

So we can use it :)